# Environment Variable To Register Libraries From Custom Location (OCX, DLL)

Tags: dll, vb6, environment-variables, ocx

I've searched far an wide for this specific problem, but I only find separate solutions for each problem individually. **I basically want to know what the name of the environment variable should be**. My assumption is that the name of the variable should be the name of the component and that it should be User variable and not System variable, for example:

```
name -> "mydll.dll"
path -> "c:\myCustomPath\mydll.dll"
```

The reason why I want to do this is because of two reasons. First, I often run my custom made tools either directly from the source code in a VM (which is sort of a pain), or I compile it and run it in W10. However, I just cannot do that with more complex apps that have dependencies because then I would have to register tons of DLLs onto the system root, and I know that I would lose track of it easily. The second reason is because I read [**this reply**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16064936) the guy says it's not recommended to use the system root for private libraries and he also suggests using an environment variable which sounded like a good solution to my problem.

The reason why I have not tested this myself through trial and error is because I'm afraid of leaving my only computer unusable if I put something wrong in the variable. Also all the libraries and exe files that I'm using are written and compiled in VB6, so I have no easy way around it since I already tried merging the multiple projects into one on a rather small project. I ended up rewriting almost the whole thing because VB6 doesn't like public types enums, etc in private Object Classes.

Finally, I am not sure if my question should be here since it doesn't involve programming, but I just felt it would be better understood here.

Comment: I'll use my psychic powers to this incoherent question. `Set path=%path%;MyDir`. Components still need to be registered. Non COM components will be found if in the application directory (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx). You can use Registration Free COM (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) for COM components in the same location.

Comment: @CatCat I would like you to elaborate more on why my question is incoherent. I know I still need to register the components, and I didn't mentioned it because I have no problem doing that. What I don't want to do is dump my libraries into the system folder. I thought that was clear. Also, your link is really useful, I'm still working on it at the moment. However, I'd still like to know the answer to my question.

Comment: Follow up on your link. I already finished following the instructions and it worked wonders. It's a much better alternative to what I was looking for. EDIT: One quick question too. Do I need to update the GUIDs if I compile new versions of both the client and component?

Comment: Your question is filled with assumptions and you don't specify what you want. Hence my physic powers were called in to use. This is an old MS article no longer on the MS web site. The interesting stuff is the second half of the page. http://nkdanfer.blog.163.com/blog/static/102136872007721112718962/

Comment: Also VB6 help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa733715(v%3dvs.60)

Comment: I'm here again with some bad news... I did some changes to the EXE and the OCX, recompiled, and changed the manifests accordingly, but now the program won't run with error "Application-defined or object-defined error." The funny part is that the release in Windows XP inside the virtual machine runs just fine. I'm honestly not sure what I broke.

Comment: Compile it in Windows XP which also means you can debug it there. All my compiled Windows Vista programs (except the most simple) required recompiling on Windows 10 to make them work in Windows 10.

Comment: @David the recompilation problem sounds like a separate issue. Consider posting a different question for that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking **where you can place COM DLLs so that you can register them on your computer**.

The answer is - fundamentally - that **it does not matter** where they are located because registration has a "global" effect. (Simplifying a little).

Now of course there are standards or conventions for where system-wide registered DLLs should go - e.g., `Windows\SysWOW64` folder. But the point is that if you register the wrong thing, or leave out dependencies, or remove a registered DLL without unregistering it - etc. etc. - you will cause problems.

I am not aware of any environment variable that has anything to do with this basic function of COM DLLs. (I may be ignorant of something).

If you are actually using an application manifest (as maybe implied in the question) then you don't need to and should not register any DLL which is manifested.